# Magento - additional information tab - replace No with something else

Tags: php, magento

In Magento there's a default tab displaying information from product attributes as Additional Information.

Currently it displays them as for example so:

```
Brands  Brandname
Serie   Seriename
Designer    Mr Designer
Delivery time   No
Finishing   No
Height  227 mm.
Width   -
Depth   -
Projection  212,5 mm.
Download Manual -
Download Technical Specifications   No
```

My question is if there is a configuration or if I could edit the code so it displays a dash like so '-' instead of No as seen in the example above when it cannot find a value?

Width and depth seem to display a dash but delivery time and finishing for example do not. The difference between width/depth and delivery time/finishing is that width/depth are text fields and delivery/finishing are dropdowns.

Comment: yes it is product attribute & delivery/finishing are dropdowns type

Comment: http://go.magento.com/support/kb/entry/name/configurable-product-step-1-create-dropdown-attributes/

Comment: http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in Magento that affects this display behaviour is

```
//file: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php
//class:Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes
public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
//...
if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
} elseif ((string)$value == '') {
    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
} elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
    $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
}
//...
```

We can see from this code that any attribute data that evaluates to `false` or is `==''` will get the `$value` `'N/A'` or `'No'` respectively.

It does raise the important question: When are width and height set to the `$value='-'`?

I think the simplest way to change `'No'` to `'-'` is to use teh Magento Admin area to add `'-'` as an attribute option in the drop down for each attribute and tell your data-entry operators to use that instead of the blank. *The links above from Shivam will help you do that if you don't know how.*

If you want to code a solution then I suggest either:

a) Find out why width and depth are `'-'` and not `'0'`, `'No'` or `'N/A'` because if you already have code changing `'0'` or `''` to `'-'` then that is the place to also change `'No'` to `'-'`

or
b) Add to or create your own module that extends the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` class and overrides `public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())`

or
c) Hack the phtml file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` to include an `str_replace()` on `$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])` by replacing the string `'>No<'` with the string `'>-<'` (being careful that the search string is unique and by copying that file to `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml` before you hack it)

I mean:

in the file `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`

replace the line

```
<td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
```

with the line

```
<td class="data"><?php echo str_replace('>No<','>-<',$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])) ?></td>
```

but this is not a rigorous solution.